# Linear regression for Physical problem predicting complex number (absolute and phase)

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, artificial-intelligence, non-linear-regression

I am trying to do a linear regression which takes some physical measurements and then predicts various Physical values. One of these Physical values is a complex number, so I am trying to split it into two and predict the magnitude and phase seperately.

I need to constrain the magnitude to between 0 and 1. In my case the only possible values of magnitude are between zero and one. Allowing the network to predict values out of this range unlocks a range of degenerate solutions and as such the network gets nowhere near true predictions.

To constrain this I have applied a sigmoid activation function to the output for the magnitude. This sometimes works. However, the true values for the magnitude are quite near zero (order 10^{-4}, which means they are near the tail of the sigmoid. This sometimes leads to the loss and gradients becoming NaN after 100 or so epochs. Is there a better approach to predicting complex numbers, or constraining outputs of regression problems?

I have tried lowering the learning rate, increasing batch size, and used various different archetectures but have had no luck. I have also tried solving the problem without constraining the output neuron with the sigmoid function but this makes the problem so degenerate that the network cannot get close to the correct solution. I have also tried transforming the magnitude to be larger (ie close to 0.5) and then transforming it back later.

For context, my loss function is

$$L = \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_i (f_{true} - f(a_{pred}, b_{pred}, |c_{pred}|, c_{pred}^{\phi})^2$$

where $f_{true})$ is something that we know, $a$ and $b$ are things that we are trying to predict and $c$ is the complex number that we are trying to predict.

Comment: Sam, that's a really interesting problem. I see two aspects. (1) Complex target. (2) Constraint on outputs. About (1), since, as you say, you want a linear regression, my advice is to just leave the target as a complex quantity, and do all of the linear algebra in complex numbers. My guess is that the usual linear regression formulas carry over exactly the same, you just plug in complex numbers as needed, and you'll probably get complex coefficients. I know Matlab/Octave are comfortable with complex numbers, also probably R and other systems.

Comment: About (2), my advice is to just impose a sharp cut-off at magnitude = 1 instead of trying a soft constraint. A soft constraint changes all the outputs, even the ones which are falling within the constraint boundary; a hard constraint only changes the ones which are outside. If a predicted value z is too big, output z/abs(z) (i.e., same argument, magnitude  = 1) instead. I don't know whether this is provably optimal without looking into it more carefully. Try stats.stackexchange.com for further discussion; although interesting, this problem is off-topic for SO.

Comment: Many thanks for your response Robert. I will try stats.stackexchange also.

1) I'm not sure if this is possible as I can't see how gradients could be calculated directly on a complex number. I have some read some papers on networks that can handle complex numbers naturally but that would require a full archetecture / system re write.

2) I will try the sharp cutoff and update.

Comment: About gradients, my advice is to write out the whole model you are working with, and work out the algebra -- probably it is simpler to phrase everything in terms of matrix operations instead of term by term. Your model is a linear regression, isn't it? I guess I don't understand what the difficulty with a full architecture revision -- for linear regression, there's just not much there. You might or might not be able to use off the shelf software, but it's not a big deal since you just need a few matrix operations.